# Wordpress XML-RPC doesn't work on shared hosting?

Tags: vps, wordpress, xmlrpc

I have a script that auto posts to wordpress using the XML-RPC option.

I have two blogs set up (on different servers, both Linode VPS's) and a third Linode VPS.

The third server submits the XML RPC post to both other servers and posts on both of them without any problems.

I have recently bought a shared hosting account (on CrocWeb if it makes any difference), and for some reason, I can't get the XML-RPC script to post to that server (from the same third Linode VPS).

I have compared the phpinfo on both, looks pretty much the same. Can you think of anything?

Note: I have contacted Crocweb support and they have added a rule on their firewall to allow access from my third Linode VPS, further to that, I can `wget` the crocweb server's homepage from the third VPS, so it's not a firewall issue I guess.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any errors when you try to run it?  Do you get a 200 answer back, or a 500?  Does your error log file show anything (You might have to ask your host if you don't know where this is).

There's so many things that it could be, we really need more information on it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same kind of problem a few weeks ago.
I use the IXR PHP Library, and I was unable to post new article to Wordpress.

I discovered a bug or incompatibility with the new version of the xmlrpc.php file.
I reverted this file to a previous version and everything went back to normal.